Tefilin on Tisha Be'Av according the Chida
What is the minhag for tefillin on Tisha Be'Av according to the Chida?
At Shacharit or only at Mincha?

can you explain why you feel he had a different minhag?

See footnote 21 in this article that the Chida's minhag was to put on tefillin at home and daven. He then went to shul and joined a minyan without tefillin for kinot and kriat hatorah.

The Ben Ish Chai's similarly says to put on tefillin at home and say the Shema and then go to shul and daven as he explains in Ben Ish Chai parashat Devarim, Year 1

Does the Chida would make a bracha on tefilin put at Sha'harit? And what is the practice of the Arizal?
